# Firebase Firestore Update Array - Multiple Write Requests

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know it's not possible to update an array within a document directly in Firestore by index, and you have to do it on the client side.

What happens when you have multiple concurrent users writing to the array of the particular document? How do we ensure that the updates to an array is made on the latest version of the document?

For example, when user A queries the document on the client side to update the array, there might have been an new update to the array made by user B that took place shortly after the query took place. Now if user A updates that array, it will be on an old version of the document, and if user A writes back to the database it will essentially overwrite user B's updates...

How can this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect against concurrent writes, [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). They protect against the scenario you describe by performing a compare-and-set (in the case of the client-side SDKs) or a lock (in the case of the Admin SDKs).